# How to cancel other threads as soon as one completed thread satisfies condition

Tags: c#, async-await, task, dotnet-httpclient, cancellation-token

I have an ASP.NET MVC application which needs to check if something exists at 3 remote API servers. The application passes an ID to each API and it returns either true or false. The code looks like this.

```
public class PingController
{
    public async Task<bool> IsFound(int id)
    {
        var servers = new ['a.com', b.com', 'c.com'];
        var result = await foundAtServers(id, servers);
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<bool> foundAtServers(int id, string[] servers)
    {
        var tasks = from server in servers
                    select checkServer(id, server);

        return await.Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());
    }

    private async Task<bool> checkServer(id, server)
    {
         var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, server+"/api/exists"+id);
         var client = new HttpClient();

         var task = await client.SendAsync(request);
         var response = await task.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

         return bool.Parse(response);
    }
}
```

This code currently checks all 3 APIs asynchronously but will wait until ALL of the HttpClient calls have completed before the MVC Action can return.

As soon as one API returns true I want to immediately return true on the Action, rather than wait for the other tasks to complete.

The C# Task class has .WaitAll and .WaitAny, but these won't work either. As I need to cancel the other HttpClient request, I presume I need to use a CancellationToken but I don't know how to use it with this structure.

Cheers.

Comment: You could use the `.WhenAny` and then a `.ContinueWith` where you cancel the other operations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to immediately return, you can use `Task.WhenAny` instead of `Task.WhenAll`. This *won't* cancel the on-going tasks, but it will enable you to return as soon as possible:

```
private async Task<bool> FoundAtServersAsync(int id, string[] servers)
{
    var tasks = (from server in servers
                 select checkServer(id, server)).ToList();

    while (tasks.Count > 0)
    {
        var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
        if (finishedTask.Result)
        {
            return finishedTask.Result;
        }

        tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
    }
    return false;
}
```

This will discard the other tasks. This means that if any exception is thrown inside one of them, it will be swallowed.

**Edit:**

If you care about actually canceling the other tasks, consider passing your `CancellationToken` to the [overload of `SendAsync` which takes one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138136(v=vs.118).aspx), and calling `CancellationTokenSource.Cancel` once a value is received. Note this will mean you'll also need to handle the `OperationCanceledException` they will throw.

If they don't matter, i'd simply discard them as above.

Comment: Will this actually cancel the incomplete Task when it returns, bearing in mind the HttpClient only offers async methods (HttpClient.SendAsync) so the checkServer method could still be waiting?

Comment: @peter No, this wont cancel the tasks. But, if you want them to be canceled, you could pass the token to `SendAsync` and invoke `cts.Cancel()` once you get a first `true`

Comment: @peter Why would you think it isn't?

Comment: Thought it might leave the CPU spinning? Not sure how **while** interacts with an **async** method.

Comment: @peter It will asynchronously wait for the task to complete. It won't spin the CPU like a synchronous loop with no sleep.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is made easier by using the following method to take a sequence of tasks and order them based on when they are completed.

```
public static IEnumerable<Task<T>> Order<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var taskList = tasks.ToList();

    var taskSources = new BlockingCollection<TaskCompletionSource<T>>();

    var taskSourceList = new List<TaskCompletionSource<T>>(taskList.Count);
    foreach (var task in taskList)
    {
        var newSource = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
        taskSources.Add(newSource);
        taskSourceList.Add(newSource);

        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            var source = taskSources.Take();

            if (t.IsCanceled)
                source.TrySetCanceled();
            else if (t.IsFaulted)
                source.TrySetException(t.Exception.InnerExceptions);
            else if (t.IsCompleted)
                source.TrySetResult(t.Result);
        }, CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.PreferFairness,
        TaskScheduler.Default);
    }

    return taskSourceList.Select(tcs => tcs.Task);
}
```

With this you can write:

```
public static async Task<bool> WhenAny(this IEnumerable<Task<bool>> tasks)
{
    foreach (var task in tasks.Order())
        if (await task)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 1. You can simply return `taskSources.Select(tcs => tcs.Task).ToList()` and lose the list. 2. I would also use `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.
Otherwise very nice and original solution.

Comment: @i3arnon 1. Not if any of the task are completed immediately.  You could end up having taken a task out of the BC (in the continuation) by the time you're done iterating the task list.

Answer (score 1):

You could wait for the first task to complete - if it's successful, return true immediately. Otherwise, wait for the next one to complete, and so on and so forth.

```
private async Task<bool> foundAtServers(int id, string[] servers)
{
    var tasks = servers.Select(server => checkServer(id, server))
                       .ToList();

    while(tasks.Any())
    {
        var task = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

        if(task.Result)
            return true;

        tasks.Remove(task);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: @peter.swallow yes, of course. It conveys your intent in a clear and concise manner: "do this while the list is not empty"